# ERROR: compilation failed for package - Undefined reference to `PackageName_rcpp_hello'

Tags: r, rcpp

I am trying to build a package but the Cpp bit is causing an error. This package is very similar to another one which also has a cpp bit and I do manage to build it without problems. 
I have checked usual errors like:

- Not having the linkingTo Rccp in the DESCRIPTION as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16259299/error-when-compiling-rcpp-code-in-an-r-package-using-rstudio/16260937).
- Remove xxx.o and xxx.so files in the src/ and try to compile and also
  the RccpExports.R as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44147065/rcppcompileattributes-error).
- I tried `Compile(".")` and
  `tools::package_native_routine_registration_skeleton(".")` although I
  do not really understand what they mean...

The error

```
* installing to library 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library'
* installing *source* package 'PackageName' ...
** libs
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c init.c -o init.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/Rcpp/include"   -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -mtune=core2 -c rcpp_hello.cpp -o rcpp_hello.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o PackageName.dll tmp.def RcppExports.o init.o rcpp_hello.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
init.o:init.c:(.rdata+0x28): undefined reference to `PackageName_rcpp_hello'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
no DLL was created
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'PackageName'
* removing 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.0/library/PackageName'

Exited with status 1.
```

Details on my session:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
Rstudio: 1.1.383
Rcpp: Rcpp_0.12.12
```

Comment: Please run `compileAttributes()` from your package directory.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel It yields nothing: 
compileAttributes(".")

Comment: That is a little odd.  Are you sure `getwd()` returns the directory also containing `DESCRIPTION` and `NAMESPACE`?  In any event, why don't you start with a freshly produced package using `Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackagenamehere")`?  That function is well tested.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel When I run `getwd' I get the directory containing `DESCRIPTION' and `NAMESPACE'. Unfortunately I cannot start from 0 as I am joining a package started by my colleague.

Comment: Starting with a _temporary package_ may aid your understanding, allows you to compare, and to establish that your toolchain is correctly setup.  I was not suggesting to throw your existing package away.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel So you are suggesting that I start a new Rstudio package project file and test if Rcpp.package.skeleton("mypackagenamehere") works?

Comment: Yes. To give you a baseline.  And _if_ you are in RStudio then `compileAttributes()` gets called for you anyway.  You should have said that earlier.  Now my guess is that you forgot to set up `NAMESPACE`.  Compare with the created package, and adapt.

Comment: 1/ Using version control, can you try `usethis::use_rcpp()`?
2/ Do you include external librairies like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38575678/6103040)?

Comment: @F.Privé I've got: 
`> use_rcpp()
✔ Adding 'Rcpp' to LinkingTo field in DESCRIPTION
✔ Setting 'Rcpp' version to * field in DESCRIPTION
✔ Adding '*.o', '*.so', '*.dll' to 'src/.gitignore'
● Include the following roxygen tags somewhere in your package
Copying code to clipboard:
  #' @useDynLib PackageName, .registration = TRUE
  #' @importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp
  NULL
● Run document()`

Comment: @F.Privé I pasted the following at the end of NAMESPACE

`@useDynLib USMunis, .registration = TRUE 

importFrom Rcpp sourceCpp

NULL`

The result of `devtools::document()` yields an error: `"Undefined reference to PackageName_rcpp_hello [...] No DLL was created".`

Comment: Is your package on GitHub?

Comment: @F.Privé No, it is a private package. I found the solution. There seems to be a problem between Rcpp 0.12.10 and Rcpp 0.12.12. My colleagues created a package with the 10 version and I wasn't able to build it in the 12 version. Additionally, it seems that R. 3.4.0 does not fully delete the Rcpp package in the library when I was downgrading it so a .dll file was still left there when I was reinstalling it. I had to manually delete all the files to actually downgrade the Rcpp package.

Comment: Sounds like it is due to the change we had to make because of R change.  You need to just re-run `compileAttributes()` under the new version -- but sadly one time you need to run it twice.  This has come up before, there is no elegant way to deal with it.  Sorry.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel The Rcpp is still a great tool. I thank you for all your great work in this and other packages! And for all your help in SO too!

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Maybe you can post an answer with the cause and many possible solutions to try so that people with the same problem can find the solution here.

Comment: @F.Privé This is already [Rcpp FAQ Answer 5.7](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-FAQ.pdf)